# Should a class constructor initialize default properties with null or undefined

Tags: javascript, constructor, ecmascript-6

When predefining class properties in a constructor is it more appropriate to initialize the property with `null` or `undefined`?

```
class PostViewer {
    constructor() {
        this.frontend = true
        this.editor = undefined // or should use `null`?
        this.key = undefined // or should use `null`?
        this.container = undefined // or should use `null`?
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems entirely arbitrary, so I don't see any way for someone to offer a factual answer that isn't just their opinion.

Comment: If you set it as undefined you're redundant, better let it without assignation.

Comment: I have been declaring them because the classes are being used within a Vue project... and by declaring the property in the constructor I don't have to add and declare the property as a watched one with vue [ex: `window.vueeventbus.$set(obj, 'key', key)`]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend not setting them at all, or if you must, use `null`.

**The reason:**

Setting them to `undefined` is (almost) indistinguishable from not setting them at all. The only difference being that using the `in` operator (and related functions, such as `hasOwnProperty`) would return true if those fields are explicitly set to `undefined`.

So it would be better to use `null` so that both types of common existence checks: `"foo" in bar` and `bar.foo !== undefined` both return the same value (either they're both true, or both false).

Comment: If performance is a concern, not setting them at all is a big performance hit because it means engines can't optimize instances for the correct hidden class up front.

Answer (score 0):

By default the javascript assigns undefined to its variables. But null is a type in java on the other hand undefined is premitive value. So that depends on the use, what it should be. But if you compare them

> undefined == null

it will return true. But

> var somevar;

and

> var somevar=undefined;

are also same in most cases.